# Limit of implicit function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, roots

For $v>0$, let $f(v)$ be the smallest positive solution $x$ of
$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{v}{x}\right)^2-1}=\tan x.$$
It can be confirmed graphically that $f(v)$ exists for all $v>0$. How can I show that
$$ \lim_{v \to \infty} f(v) = \frac{\pi}{2}?$$

Comment: If *only* graphically can be proved that $\;f(v)\;$ exists for all reals, then perhaps the "proof" of the limit is graphic...? Besides this, for $\;v=0\;$ we have $\;\sqrt{-1}=\tan x\;$ . Are you considering complex valued functions?

Comment: @Timbuc Sorry, typo. I left out the restriction $v>0$. It has now been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x(v)$ be the solution for each $v$. You can show such a solution exists for all positive $v$ by a number of methods, one being by looking at the function $g_v(x)=\tan(x)-\sqrt{(v/x)^2-1}$ and showing that for $v>\pi$: $g(1)>0$, $g(\pi)<0$, so by continuity a solution always exists. This also implies $0<x(v)<\pi$, meaning that it's bounded.

Now we just need to show that $x(v)$ is increasing. This is easy because looking at $g_v(x)$, for fixed $x$, increasing $v$ makes $g_v(x)$ negative, and since $\tan(x)$ blows up at half integer multiples of $\pi$, we get that $x(v)$ is increasing. You need a bit more rigor here, work it through. So $x(v)$ has a limit as $v\rightarrow\infty$.

Using the fact that $x(v)=\arctan(\sqrt{(v/x(v))^2-1})$ and that $(v/x(v))$ is going to infinity as $x\rightarrow\infty$, we get $\lim_{v\rightarrow\infty} x(v) = \lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} \arctan(z)=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x>0$, then $\tan x=\sqrt{\left(\frac{v}{x}\right)^2-1} \to +\infty$ as $v\to +\infty$. So $x=\arctan x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ as $v\to +\infty$. And $x$ is asked to be smallest positive solution, hence $x=\frac\pi 2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is the smallest positive solution to $\sqrt{\left(\frac{v}{x}\right)^2-1}=\tan x$, then $0\le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\left(\frac{v}{x}\right)^2-1=\tan^2 x$, from which we know that $\frac{v}{x} =\sec x$. Thus $f(v)$ = $g^{-1}(v)$, where $g(x)=x\sec(x)$. The graph of $y=g(x)$ is positive and increasing on $0\le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and approaches a vertical asymptote at $x=\pi/2$, so the graph of $y=g^{-1}(v)$ is increasing with a horizontal asymptote at $y=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$
g_v(x) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{v}{x}\right)^2-1}-\tan x.
$$

Then for fixed $v$

$$
\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-} g_v(x) = -\infty,
$$

and for fixed $x$

$$
\lim_{v \to \infty} g_v(x) = \infty.
$$

Now use the intermediate value theorem to show that, for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$, $g_v(x)$ has a zero $x = f(v)$ in the interval $(\pi/2-\epsilon,\pi/2)$ for $v$ large enough.

Comment: For reference, the solution can be expanded in series like $$f(v) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2v} + \frac{\pi}{2v^2} - \frac{\pi^3+24\pi}{48v^3} + \cdots.$$

Comment: Interesting. How did you obtain this series expansion?

Comment: I first checked with the inverse function theorem to find that $f(v)$ was an analytic function of $1/v$.  After that it's a matter of substituting $x = \tfrac{\pi}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k v^{-k}$, expanding things in power series, and comparing coefficients, which I did with the help of Mathematica.